# How to implement a generic parameter that isn't generic

Tags: c#, generics

I have an interface with two generic parameters, but one of the parameters is expected to be provided by the class implementation.

```
public interface IA<T, U> { ... }
public class X<T> : IA<T, int> { ... }
public class Y<T> : IA<T, MyClass> { ... }
```

However, another interface have a method that takes an instance of `IA` as a parameter - however, every instance must be the same (the same class can take multiples `X`, but then it will never take a `Y`, or vice-versa). I tried to put it as a generic constrainst, but then I have something like

```
public interface IB<T, U, V> where U : IA<T, V> {
   void MyMethod(U value);
}
public class Z<T> : IB<T, X<T>, int> { ... }
```

Of course, I don't want to write that parameter `V`, as I can't choose a value for it. The parameter `U` already dictates what the value of V should be! However, I can't simply remove `V`, because then I couldn't write the constraint.

---

Another solution is to not use the constraint:

```
public interface IB<T> {
   void MyMethod(IA<T> value);
}
```

But this way, I can't ensure the implementation of `IB` will receive only one implementation of `IA` (ie. it will be able to receive both `X` and `Y`, and it should not).

---

Is there any way to avoid the creation of the generic parameter `V` in the interface `IB` (in the first solution) while still mutually-excluding the implementations of `IA`? Is there any specific reason the compiler can't infer the type of `V` and allow me to write only `class Z<T> : IB<T, X<T>>` or this case just wasn't expected in the language specs/was chosen to not be implemented?

Comment: Interface `IB` should have the same generic arguments as `IA`. I don't see why you needed to pass `X<T>` as a type. You have enough to define `MyMethod(IA<T,U> value)` which would restrict it to `X` or `Y` but not both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have enough generic types to restrict `IB<T,U>.MyMethod()` from receiving both `X` and `Y`. You just need to define the method argument as accepting on a specific type.

```
    public interface IA<T,U> {}
    public class X<T> : IA<T,int> {}
    public class Y<T> : IA<T,string> {}

    public interface IB<T,U>
    {
        void MyMethod(IA<T,U> value);
    }

    IB<int,int> foo;
    X<int> a;
    Y<int> b;

    foo.MyMethod(a); // will compile
    foo.MyMethod(b); // will not compile
```

> Is there any way to avoid the creation of the generic parameter V in the interface IB (in the first solution) while still mutually-excluding the implementations of IA? Is there any specific reason the compiler can't infer the type of V and allow me to write only class Z : IB> or this case just wasn't expected in the language specs/was chosen to not be implemented?

I don't think that's how inference works in C#. To infer the type for `U` the `MyMethod` would be written like this.

```
    public interface IB<T>
    {
        void MyMethod<U>(IA<T,U> value);
    }

    IB<int> foo = null;
    X<int> a;
    foo.MyMethod(a); // int type is inferred by compiler
```

You still have to use `IA<T,U>` in your `IB` interface. I don't think there is an easy way around that.

Comment: That's correct, thanks. While the type in my question is logically infer-able, that is because there is a redundancy of types.

Comment: @Mephy if I understand correctly, you wanted to remove `IA` from being used by `IB`. I'm not sure you can (or at least easily).

Comment: @MathewFoscarini No, I don't. There was just a duplicate because I needed to specify the `U` parameter of `IA` and the `V` parameter of `IB` to be the same. Your answer works just fine, I'm able to remove the `U` parameter of `IB` without problem.